# Does decentralization infer distribution?

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing

I'm exploring the relationship between decentralization and distribution, and I've come to a question for which I've found no real explanation.  Does the qualification of a system as "decentralized" infer that the system is distributed?

Using the practical example of a star topology in which the central node sends directives to edge nodes, it can be seen that a centralized system can be distributed (centralization does not infer non-distribution).

Is there a practical example of a system that is decentralized but not distributed?  Is such a relationship possible?

Comment: You probably mean *imply* and not *infer*, don't you?

Comment: Surely I've _implied_ a certain question, and you can _infer_ the proper meaning.  I'm not sure how much your comment contributes to the discussion other than pointing out inconsequential grammar mistakes.

Comment: Well, why don't you use the proper word then? What if I had not seen the answers (the so called "discussion") because I saw your question through review? What if I was not a native english speaker and didn't know for sure there wasn't some sort of idiom that allowed the use of the verb *infer* to mean *imply*? Now I realize there is not, and rather than blaming me for asking you to clarify, you could simply fix your question. Things don't infer. People do. Not my fault.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference in "decentralized" and "distributed" tends to be one of intensity. You could fairly think of it as a spectrum, with "centralized" on one side, "distributed" on the other, and "decentralized" as an inbetween or hybrid state.

A nice example from [distributed economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_economy):

[image: comparison image]

In this definition the distinction is if there is a command-control style of setup, with any node having a superior position to other nodes, or if the system is distributed such that all (or at least most) nodes are peers.

The other important consideration is the "what" - *what* are you distributing? In a typical star topology (really predating the relatively recent concept of distributed computing), clients were 'remote' but nothing was actually 'distributed' in this sense ('communicated' or 'networked' or 'transmitted', all being quite distinct from distributed). Every node acted on it's own, though the central node often has special status (control, switching, monitoring, etc). In distributed systems we usually refer to something such as distributed computation or distributed file-sharing.

This last fact of 'what' allows a system to be centralized in some respects (such as having a canonical/single database), decentralized in others (redundant control/backup/overflow systems), and distributed in others (all nodes share public files freely with one another). And in all these cases all nodes may be 'remote', in that they are not physically close to one another - or they could all be running in the same virtual machine on a single device.

So in the end, we see that at least given this set of definitions/uses, decentralized and distributed mean different things, but are fundamentally related in the same way that "gray" is related to "black".

I should also warn you that these uses are often garbled together (especially when people start talking about "the cloud"), and so this might not hold for that conversation and you may need to consider alternate definitions. In other words - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your statement about how a centralized system may be distributed, I believe it also infers that a decentralized system can be non-distributed.

As I understand it, a centralized, yet distributed system, surely refers to the characterization of centralization at a conceptual level rather than the underlying implementation. Similarly, one could write a localized, yet decentralized, system, such as a logging system. Open multiple ports on your machine, and bind different loggers to each port, I believe that proves the point.

If that's not the case, I might be missing something obvious.